# Amazon AWS Cognito Identity Pool Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Some days ago I have created an Identity Pool. My region is eu-west-1.
And today I don't know how to see the information relative to this:
when I go to the Amazon Cognito console, it says me:

> Region not supported
>
> Cognito User Pools are currently only available in US East (Virginia).

And after it only propose me to create a new User Pool.

So why the console say me that Cognito is only available in US East in spite of I could created a pool for my region which is EU West and how can I access to my identity pool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter Cognito Console, you should select 'Manage Federated Identities' and not 'Manage User Pools' to see your identity pools.

Cognito User Pools is a new service that allows you to easily provide sign up and sign in functionality to your users and is only available in us-east-1.